# How can I learn all the options I can pass to DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS?

Tags: dpkg, cross-compilation

I'm compiling debian packages with xdeb, and I'm trying to understand how this variable `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS` works and I might be able to specify 32-bit over 64-bit for a userspace app.  The best way I've found so far to learn it's usage is from search suggestions.

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="nodocs notest nocheck" DEB_STAGE="stage1" xdeb \
    --no-native-import \
    --config-file xdeb.cfg \
    --architecture armhf \
    --build-directory mybuilddir \
    --dest-directory mydestdir \
    ebtables \
    --no-lintian
```

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ebtables/2.0.10.4-3ubuntu1

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xdeb.1.html

Answer (score 4):

See section 4.9.1

> nocheck This tag says to not run any build-time test suite provided by
>   the package.
>
> noopt The presence of this tag means that the package should be
>   compiled with a minimum of optimization. For C programs, it is best to
>   add -O0 to CFLAGS (although this is usually the default). Some
>   programs might fail to build or run at this level of optimization; it
>   may be necessary to use -O1, for example.
>
> nostrip This tag means that the debugging symbols should not be
>   stripped from the binary during installation, so that debugging
>   information may be included in the package.
>
> parallel=n This tag means that the package should be built using up to
>   n parallel processes if the package build system supports this.[27] If
>   the package build system does not support parallel builds, this string
>   must be ignored. If the package build system only supports a lower
>   level of concurrency than n, the package should be built using as many
>   parallel processes as the package build system supports. It is up to
>   the package maintainer to decide whether the package build times are
>   long enough and the package build system is robust enough to make
>   supporting parallel builds worthwhile.

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#debian-rules-and-deb-build-options

Comment: And supposedly the way to execute `dpkg-buildpackage` is, e.g. `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS='noopts nostrip' dpkg-buildpackage`.